# Log scale on gephi reports

Tags: network-programming

I am new to Gephi, and I am computing a small world network. I want to plot reports from the statistical modules in gephi in log-log scale (otherwise it is hardly possible to see anything in the degree distribution).

I would like to obtain the raw data results to plot them on gnuplot, or just use the console in gephi to see them. I googled the issue and looked in the gephi forums but could not seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Data Laboratory and click on "export table". It will export a spreadsheet of the node attributes including the degree.